# AWS: what's the point in using CloudFront for API requests instead of routing them to ALB directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-alb

I have a load balancer (ALB) that is dealing with my app's API requests (alb.domain.com) . I also have an S3 bucket where my static site is served from via CloudFront (domain.com). I have configured a distribution so that /api goes to the ALB and the rest goes to S3 and all works fine. However, instead of routing my API requests to CloudFront (domain.com/api), I can also route them directly to the ALB (alb.domain.com/api), which also works fine. I don't need caching on my API requests so i disabled it on the distribution anyway. What would be the point in me doing the requests via CloudFront given that I am (1) introducing an extra connection in the route and (2) my requests are now calculated for CloudFront pricing. Are there any disadvantages associated with just routing requests directly to the ALB and using CloudFront only for serving static files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of benefits to using CloudFront in your scenario (and generally).

Firstly by having route through CloudFront it gives the impression this is a single domain, this removes implementation of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), helps to reduce complexities in any security configurations (such as [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)). Additionally you can cache any static based requests, or those that change infrequently in the future if you need it.

You also gain the benefits that you get access to the [edge network to do routing](https://infrastructure.aws/), this benefits for clients that are further away from the region. This means that the user will hit the closest edge location to them, which will then route and establish a connection with the origin over the private AWS network (which will be faster than traversing the public internet).

Additionally security evaluations at the Edge, both [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) and [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) can be evaluated closer to the user on AWS Edge infrastructure rather than your own resources.